# C# XML deserialization with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2015-12-16'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.0933'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='133.18'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

which I'm trying to deserialize with:

```
[XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = EcbNameSpace)]
public class EcbEnvelope
{
    const string EcbNameSpace = "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01";

    [XmlElement("Sender", Namespace = EcbNameSpace)]
    public string EcbSender { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("subject", Namespace = EcbNameSpace)]
    public string EcbSubject { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Cube")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Cube")]
    public List<CubeRoot> CubeRootEl { get; set; }

    public class CubeRoot
    {
        [XmlAttribute("time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Cube")]
        public List<CubeItem> CubeItems { get; set; }

        public class CubeItem
        {
            [XmlAttribute("rate")]
            public string RateStr { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            public decimal Rate
            {
                get { return decimal.Parse(RateStr); }
            }

            [XmlAttribute("currency")]
            public string Currency { get; set; }
        }
    }   
}
```

However, it deserializes CubeRootEl as empty list. If I remove namspaces from XML, then it deserializes successfully. What am I doing wrong? I tried adding empty namespaces to CubeRootEl in code, but also unsuccessfully.

Here's the code used for deserialization:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EcbEnvelope)); 
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pathToFile)) 
    var a = serializer.Deserialize(streamReader) as EcbEnvelope; 
}
```

Comment: What code do you use for deserialization?

Comment: var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EcbEnvelope));
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
{
   var a = serializer.Deserialize(streamReader) as EcbEnvelope;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You do not specify a namespace for the property `public List<CubeRoot> CubeRootEl`.  When a namespace for a property is not specified, `XmlSerializer` *assumes it to be in the same namespace as the containing element*, which would in this case be `"http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"`.  But the `<Cube>` elements are not in this namespace since they do not have the `"gesmes:"` prefix.
2. Your XML has a default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"`.  Thus the `<Cube>` elements are actually in this namespace.
3. `Sender` is not a simple string-valued element, it has a nested element `<gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>`.

Fixing these three issues allows your XML to be deserialized:

```
[XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = GesmesNameSpace)]
public class EcbEnvelope
{
    public const string GesmesNameSpace = "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01";
    public const string EcbNameSpace = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

    [XmlElement("Sender", Namespace = GesmesNameSpace)]
    public EcbSender Sender { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("subject", Namespace = GesmesNameSpace)]
    public string EcbSubject { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Cube", Namespace = EcbNameSpace)]
    [XmlArrayItem("Cube")]
    public List<CubeRoot> CubeRootEl { get; set; }

    public class EcbSender
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CubeRoot
    {
        [XmlAttribute("time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Cube")]
        public List<CubeItem> CubeItems { get; set; }

        public class CubeItem
        {
            [XmlAttribute("rate")]
            public string RateStr { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            public decimal Rate
            {
                get { return decimal.Parse(RateStr); }
            }

            [XmlAttribute("currency")]
            public string Currency { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```